# How do I use a GUI to open a directory in Python 3?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to find the string value of the directory in Python where a few files are located. Then, I plan on using `os.listdir` to continue on with the script. I've tried using `tkFileDialog` to use `askdirectory`, but not luck.

Answer (score 10):

tkFileDialog changed with Python 3.x, it's now `tkinter.filedialog`, a module of `tkinter`

Here's how to import it:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

folder = askdirectory()
```

Refer to: http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules

Comment: Hei. I'm getting this tkinter window pop and folder choosing popup both. How do I close this tkinter popup? It's not closing after choosing the folder in folder popup automatically.

Comment: Close the root window

### import tkinter as tk 
# root = tk.Tk() 
# root.withdraw() ###