# Iterating through subdirectories to add unique strings to each file

Tags: python, for-loop, replace

**My goal:** To build a program that:

- Opens a folder (provided by the user) from the user's computer
- Iterates through that folder, opening each document in each subdirectory (named according to language codes; "AR," "EN," "ES," etc.)
- Substitutes a string in for another string in each document. Crucially, the new string will change with each document (though the old string will not), according to the language code in the folder name.

**My level of experience:** Minimal; been learning python for a few months but this is the first program I'm building that's not paint-by-numbers. I'm building it to make a process at work faster. I'm sure I'm not building this as efficiently as possible; I've been throwing it together from my own knowledge and from reading stackexchange religiously while building it.

**Research I've done on my own:** I've been living in stackexchange the past few days, but I haven't found anyone doing quite what I'm doing (which was very surprising to me). I'm not sure if this is just because I lack the vocabulary to search (tried out a lot of search terms, but none of them totally match what I'm doing) or if this is just the wrong way of going about things.

**The issue I'm running into:**
I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test5.py", line 52, in <module>
    for f in os.listdir(src_dir):
OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'ExploringEduTubingEN(1).txt'
```

I'm not sure how to iterate through every file in the subdirectories and update a string within each file (*not* the file names) with a new and unique string. I thought I had it, but this error has totally thrown me off. Prior to this, I was getting an error for the same line that said "Not a file or directory: 'ExploringEduTubingEN(1).txt'" and it's surprising to me that the first error could request a file *or* a directory, and once I fixed that, it asked for just a directory; seems like it should've just asked for a directory at the beginning.

With no further ado, **the code** (placing at bottom because it's long to include context):

```
import os

ex=raw_input("Please provide an example PDF that we'll append a language code to. ")
#Asking for a PDF to which we'll iteratively append the language codes from below.

lst = ['_ar.pdf', '_cs.pdf', '_de.pdf', '_el.pdf', '_en_gb.pdf', '_es.pdf', '_es_419.pdf',
'_fr.pdf', '_id.pdf', '_it.pdf', '_ja.pdf', '_ko.pdf', '_nl.pdf', '_pl.pdf', '_pt_br.pdf', '_pt_pt.pdf', '_ro.pdf', '_ru.pdf',
'_sv.pdf', '_th.pdf', '_tr.pdf', '_vi.pdf', '_zh_tw.pdf', '_vn.pdf', '_zh_cn.pdf']
#list of language code PDF appending strings.

pdf_list=open('pdflist.txt','w+')
#creating a document to put this group of PDF filepaths in.

pdf2='pdflist.txt'
#making this an actual variable.

for word in lst:
  pdf_list.write(ex + word + "\n")
#creating a version of the PDF example for every item in the language list, and then appending the language codes.

pdf_list.seek(0)
langlist=pdf_list.readlines()
#creating a list of the PDF paths so that I can use it below.

for i in langlist:
    i=i.rstrip("\n")
#removing the line breaks.

pdf_list.close()
#closing the file after removing the line breaks.

file1=raw_input("Please provide the full filepath of the folder you'd like to convert. ")
#the folder provided by the user to iterate through.
folder1=os.listdir(file1)
#creating a list of the files within the folder
pdfpath1="example.pdf"
langfile="example2.pdf"
#setting variables for below

#my thought here is that i'd need to make the variable the initial folder, then make it a list, then iterate through the list.


for ogfile in folder1:
    #want to iterate through all the files in the directory, including in subdirectories
    src_dir=ogfile.split("/",6)
    src_dir="/".join(src_dir[:6])
    #goal here is to cut off the language code folder name and then join it again, w/o language code.
    for f in os.listdir(src_dir):
        f = os.path.join(src_dir, f)
        #i admit this got a little convoluted–i'm trying to make sure the files put the right code in, I.E. that the document from the folder ending in "AR" gets the PDF that will now end in "AR"
        #the perils of pulling from lots of different questions in stackexchange
        with open(ogfile, 'r+') as f:
            content = f.read()
            f.seek(0)
            f.truncate()
            for langfile in langlist:
                f.write(content.replace(pdfpath1, langfile))
                #replacing the placeholder PDF link with the created PDF links from the beginning of the code
```

If you read this far, thanks. I've tried to provide as much information as possible, especially about my thought process. I'll keep trying things and reading, but I'd love to have more eyes on it.

Comment: Are your input files really pdf files? Or simple text files?

Comment: PDF files, unfortunately. They're external documents that we send out; we have a team that generates links according a standard template, so I figured this was a way to save time and not actually make the user input those PDF links.

The part of the process I'm trying to eliminate is us going into each of these documents and adding the unique PDFs from this team.

Comment: I see, this is not as simple as opening a file and replace the text as you are trying to do (which would be easy with text files). You have two questions here: 1) iterating through a list of files which is the easy bit, and 2) replacing the text content within a pdf file (if I understood correctly). I suggest to open a separate question for the second problem.

Comment: er, no, sorry. i misunderstood your question. the string i am *inputting* into a text file is, in fact, a link to a PDF ("example2.pdf" replaces "example.pdf"), but the file i'm editing is just a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the full path to your directories/files. Use `os.path.join` to create a valid path to your file or directory (and platform-independent).

For replacing your string, simply modify your example string using the subfolder name. Assuming that `ex` as the format `filename.pdf`, you could use: `newstring = ex[:-4] + '_' + str.lower(subfolder) + '.pdf'`. That way, you do not have to specify the list of replacement strings nor loop through this list.

**Solution**

To iterate over your directory and replace the content of your files as you'd like, you can do the following:

```
# Get the name of the file: "example.pdf" (note the .pdf is assumed here)
ex=raw_input("Please provide an example PDF that we'll append a language code to. ")

# Get the folder to go through
folderpath=raw_input("Please provide the full filepath of the folder you'd like to convert. ")

# Get all subfolders and go through them (named: 'AR', 'DE', etc.)
subfolders=os.listdir(folderpath)

for subfolder in subfolders:
    # Get the full path to the subfolder
    fullsubfolder = os.path.join(folderpath,subfolder)

    # If it is a directory, go through it
    if os.path.isdir(fullsubfolder):
        # Find all files in subdirectory and go through each of them
        files = os.listdir(fullsubfolder)
        for filename in files:
            # Get full path to the file
            fullfile = os.path.join(fullsubfolder, filename)

            # If it is a file, process it (note: we do not check if it is a text file here)
            if os.path.isfile(fullfile):
                with open(fullfile, 'r+') as f: 
                    content = f.read()
                    f.seek(0)
                    f.truncate()

                    # Create the replacing string based on the subdirectory name. Ex: 'example_ar.pdf'
                    newstring = ex[:-4] + '_' + str.lower(subfolder) + '.pdf'
                    f.write(content.replace(ex, newstring))
```

**Note**

Instead of asking the user to find write the folder, you could ask him to open the directory with a dialog box. See this question for more info: [Use GUI to open directory in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380272/use-gui-to-open-directory-in-python-3)

Comment: thank you so much. i'm going to try this out this afternoon.

Comment: great, glad it was useful!