# How to select multiple files or an entire folder(display names of all the files it contains) in python using tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have written a code to display the contents of a file using tkinter askopenfile() method. Now I need to select an entire folder(directory) and print the names of the files it contains or select multiple files.

I'm new to the concepts of tkinter and having a difficult time understanding this. Is there any method to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use-gui-to-open-directory-in-python-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380272)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using python 2, so here you go:

```py
from Tkinter import *
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog

root = Tk()
root.filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/")

print(root.filename)
```

Hope this helps!

FYI: I would suggest you update to python 3. Python 2 has been sun-setted(on January 1st, 2020).